Joi validation error, keep getting "object not allowed"
I am using Joi for validating data from a form.Data is structured like this:
campground:title,price,description,location,image
This is the schema:
campJoiSchema = Joi.object({
    title: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
    price: Joi.number().integer().required(),
    description: Joi.string().min(3).max(100).required(),
    location: Joi.string().required(),
    image: Joi.string(),
}).options({stripUnknown:true}).required()

I am adding the correct data,but I keep getting the following error.
[Error [ValidationError]: "title" is required]

I tried to remove the options({stripUnknown:true}) and removing the "required" fields to see what happens, but then I am getting the error that the entire object "is not allowed":
`[Error [ValidationError]: "campground" is not allowed] {
  _original: {
    campground: {
      title: 'adfsdfs',
      location: 'Milwaukee, Wisconsin',
      price: '-1',
      description: 'zdfzdf',
      image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1633988826370-4953fac6245f?q=80&w=1887&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D'
    }
  },
  details: [
    {
      message: '"campground" is not allowed',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'object.unknown',
      context: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
`


Can you add more details of how you are using "campJoiSchema", where you are actually using the validator? Currently it looks like you are validating an object that looks like { campground: { title: ... }} but joi is just expecting the inner object. {title: ... }

That was the problem, the object was incorrectly structured. thanks for pointing it out!

campJoiSchema = Joi.object({
  campground:Joi.Object({            //this line u have forget bcz u r accessing 
                                    //campground array
    title: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
    price: Joi.number().integer().required(),
    description: Joi.string().min(3).max(100).required(),
    location: Joi.string().required(),
    image: Joi.string(),
}).options({stripUnknown:true}).required()
});


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
